# route issue in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, url, routes, codeigniter-3

URL: example.com/bikes/cityname/makename

I have route config as follows

```
$route['bikes']  = 'bikes/index';
$route['bikes(/:any)'] = 'bikes/bike_details$1';
$route['bikes/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'bikes/index';
```

I have this controller

```
public function index($city='',$make='')
{
 echo $city."--".$make;
 // these two are empty
```

I tried below, give me error

```
 public function index($city,$make)
 {
  // not working
```

this should work for both

```
example.com/bikes/cityname/makename
```

and

```
example.com/bikes/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*`route.php` should be like this :*

```
$route['bikes/index']  = 'bikes/index';
$route['bikes/(:any)'] = 'bikes/$1';
$route['bikes/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'bikes/$1/$2';
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

Comment: with little modification,$route['bikes/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'bikes/index/$1/$2'; it worked. thank you

Comment: instead of this you can do like this : `$route['bikes/index']  = 'bikes/index';` see my updated answer and access url with no argument  : `http://localhost/codeigniter/bikes/index` ,with one argument `http://localhost/codeigniter/bikes/index/arg1` , with two arguments `http://localhost/codeigniter/bikes/index/arg1/arg2`